# Using jQuery animated 'delete entry' effect with CakePHP?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, jquery-animate

I'm following the very basic (but brilliant) CakePHP tutorials on creating a blog using the framework.

I'm getting adventurous and would like to try use this: [Animated AJAX Record Deletion Using jQuery](http://davidwalsh.name/animated-ajax-jquery) effect with [my Delete entry script](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1539/Deleting-Posts).

Can someone explain how I can do this?

Many thanks for any pointers here :-)

Comment: be warned: this won't work with cake2 and postLink() though. if you ever plan on using the cutting edge version :)

Comment: Just curious, what will not work in cake 2.0?

Comment: I should have added it to your answer - you are assuming that mcgarriers is using cake<2.0 (although you probably are right). with cake2 this is slightly more difficult to achieve - using the default post links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Your view action:
<?php

function index() {
    //Provide your pagination info..
    $this->set('entries', $this->paginate());
}
?>

//Your delete action:
<?php

function delete($id) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->Blog->delete($id)) {
        $response = array("success" => true);
    } else {
        $response = array("success" => false);
    }
    return json_encode($response);
}
?>

//Your index.ctp
.....
<?php foreach ($entries as $entry): ?>
    <div class="record">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("controller" => "blog", "action" => "delete", $entry['Blog']['id'])) ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
        <strong><?php echo $entry['Blog']['title'] ?></strong>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

//Your Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
            var __this = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: $(__this).attr("href"),
                beforeSend: function() {
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    //Changed here
                    response = $.parseJSON(response);//console.log(response);
                    if(response.success){
                        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                            parent.remove();
                        });
                    }else{
                        alert("Failed to delete message");
                        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fff'},100);//Restore your background back
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed response. I have made a number of changes and have it working except for ONE issue. When I click 'delete' it sets the background to red then the alert says "Failed" to delete message". However, once I close this message it does indeed delete the message. Can I post my current code for your thoughts?

Comment: index.ctp -- http://pastie.org/3118824 , Posts Controller -- http://pastie.org/3118829 -- Many thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: using the above code, when i click 'delete' the background goes red, then the alert 'failed to...' appears but the row doesn't animate disappear. But it definitely deletes the record.

Comment: @mcgarriers, did you try the line I added? Also please uncomment console.log(response) and also add console.log(parent); after defining parent. Please paste the output here or in pastebin. Let see what you see then.

Comment: Hi Moiz. Sorry, I just noticed the 'edited...' bit above. That works 99% correct. It however deletes the td and not the tr. So I made this change in the 'index.ctp' file: `
   var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");`

Comment: Many thanks for your patience and help throughout this. I'm now going to look over the javascript you coded and get my head around it :-) Have a good day!!